# Difference between Oracle versions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

1. Is a SQL statement that was valid in 9i still valid in 11g?
2. Are there new features in 11g that were not available in 9i?
3. Are there behavioral differences between a valid 9i SQL statement and the same statement in 11g?

Comment: Would accept "yes" as an answer?

Comment: Are you asking "Is a SQL statement that was valid in 9i still valid in 11g?"  Are you asking "Are there new features in 11g that were not available in 9i?"  Are you asking "Are there behavioral differences between a valid 9i SQL statement and the same statement in 11g?"  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @Justin Cave: Thanks Buddy. I was unable to frame the questions. Yep.. Can you give me the answers for all the questions you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A SQL statement that was valid in 9i is still valid in 11g.  Oracle works very hard to ensure backwards compatibility.  Of course, there are occasions where an older version of Oracle accepted a SQL statement that was actually syntactically invalid rather than raising an error where a later version correctly raises an error.  But that is pretty rare.
2. If you are interested in features that have been added in different versions of Oracle, you'd be well served to look through the [SQL Language Improvements chapter of the New Features Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14214/chapter1.htm#OBJECTIVENO04030) and the [What's New in the SQL Language chapter of the SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/wnsql.htm#sthref5).
3. If you are asking about behavioral differences, those are primarily do to the reliance on faulty assumptions.  For example, a large number of folks assumed that they didn't need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause if the query contained a `GROUP BY`.  This was never an assumption that Oracle encouraged but Oracle happened to sort the data in order to do the `GROUP BY`.  When the [hash group by operation was added in 10.2](http://www.juliandyke.com/Optimisation/Operations/HashGroupBy.html), Oracle no longer always sorted the data as a byproduct of grouping the data.  That caused lots of developers to have to go back through code to add `ORDER BY` clauses.  Other SQL statements perform differently in 11g because of different optimizer settings (particularly if you are moving from the rule-based optimizer in 9i).

Answer (score 2):

> Is a SQL statement that was valid in 9i still valid in 11g

There have been occasions where previously valid SQL statements became invalid in a later version. For example, IIRC between Oracle 8 and 9, the `mod` function became illegal to use as an infix operator; i.e. `select 12 mod 3 from dual` is valid in Oracle 8, but not in Oracle 9. (`select mod(12,3) from dual` is valid in both versions)

> Are there new features in 11g that were not available in 9i

Yes, of course, but listing them would exceed the scope of this answer.

> Are there behavioral differences between a valid 9i SQL statement and the same statement in 11g

There are behavioral differences that can lead to unwanted "effects". Two examples:

1. Query optimizer. In every new version, there is a slight chance that some queries will perform significantely slower because the new query optimizer might choose a different, inferior plan than the old query optimizer.
2. Group by: Until Oracle 9i, `group by` delivered sorted results. (Not exactly the same order like `order by`, because `order by` takes account of language-specific order, like " L,M,N,O,**Ö**,P,Q" in German, while `group by` didn't, but it was  good enough for many purposes). Because of that, many developers ommited the `order by` clause when it would have been identical to the `group by` clause. That changed in Oracle 10g, apparently 10g uses a hash table instead of a sorted tree for grouping. Because of that, some programs delivered different results in 10g than in 9i. 
   *(Note: it has always been a bad idea to omit the `order by` when ordered results were expected)*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Have a look at the first chapter of the Oracle Database SQL Language References, for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/wnsql.htm#sthref5

Comment: Can you give some examples? Coz i have quite good knowledge on oracle 9i:SQL, Now i am going through oracle11g:SQL. But not finding any difference.

Comment: 10.1 new datatype BINARY_FLOAT, new function REGEXP_LIKE, the recyclebin. 11.1 PIVOT, virtual column, 11.2 deferred segment creation...